# How to send back a ExportMetricsServiceResponse correctly from a flask app to the OpenTelemetry collector

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am using a Python flask app to accept post requests from the OpenTelemetry Collector via otlphttp. I am receiving the data, however I am not sending the right ACK back to the Collector because I keep on receiving all the meter data ever sent rather than new meter data.

I read in the docs that an ExportMetricsServiceResponse should be sent back to the collector along with a 200 code but it still is not solving my problem. Also the POST coming in had data compressed in gzip, so I gzipped the response as well.

```
@app.route( rule='/update-state/v1/metrics', methods=["POST" ])
def updateState():
    # receiving and processing data ...
    emsr = ExportMetricsServiceResponse()
    response = gzip.compress(emsr.SerializeToString())
    response = make_response(response, 200)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-protobuf'
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
    return response
```